# Where should Thread.CurrentPrincipal and HttpContext.Current.User get set when using a custom Principal

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, current-principal

I created a custom class that inherits from `IPrincipal` and would like to make sure this object is added to the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and `HttpContext.Current.User` instead of the `ClaimsPrincipal` object.  This is for a web api application.

I would like this to occur after the user makes a successful request for an access token.  Where in the lifecycle should this occur?

After I called /Token to get the access_token, I passed the bearer token back to the ChangePassword action along with the necessary parameters and User is still set to ClaimsPrincipal. Is there a way to make sure the Principal is set immediately after the request is made and after the ClaimsPrincipal is set?

Comment: are you using oauth?

Comment: Yes.  I created a custom IUserStore as well.

Comment: so you are not using `IOwinContext.Authentication.SignIn` method to  set your principal?

Comment: I am using the OWIN tools that are build in when you create a new project using Individual accounts setting.  I also created a custom UserStore that inherits from IUserStore, IUserPasswordStore, etc.

Comment: in `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method before calling to `SignIn`

Comment: After I called /Token to get the access_token, I passed the bearer token back to the ChangePassword action along with the necessary parameters and User is still set to ClaimsPrincipal.  Is there a way to make sure the Principal is set immediately after the request is made and after the ClaimsPrincipal is set?